# Updating entity property values through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, properties

I have entity class structure like this as below, having json columns that are related to classes and i am in the process of updating entity with some of the values.

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "CA2227:Collection properties should be read only", Justification = "ORM", Scope = "module")]
public class DesignProject : PatchEntityProperties
{
    [Key, GraphQLNonNullType]
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public ProjectSectionStatus SectionStatuses { get; set; } = new ProjectSectionStatus();
}
```

and then the ProjectSectionStatus class looks like as below

```
public class ProjectSectionStatus
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public ProjectSectionStage ExecutiveSummarySectionStatus { get; set; } = ProjectSectionStage.NOT_STARTED;
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public ProjectSectionStage CodesAndGuidelinesSectionStatus { get; set; } = ProjectSectionStage.NOT_STARTED;
    public string CodesAndGuidelinesSectionNotesHTML { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public ProjectSectionStage AirSystemsSectionStatus { get; set; } = ProjectSectionStage.NOT_STARTED;
    public string AirSystemsSectionNotesHTML { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public ProjectSectionStage ExhaustEquipmentSectionStatus { get; set; } = ProjectSectionStage.NOT_STARTED;
    public string ExhaustEquipmentSectionNotesHTML { get; set; } = "";
    ....
    .....
    .....
}
```

below is where i am updating some of the properties in section statuses for targetdesignproject

```
 var targetDesignProject = this._dbContext.DesignProjects.Where(a => a.ProjectNumber == targetProjectNumber).SingleOrDefault();
 targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses.AirSystemsSectionStatus = Entities.Enums.ProjectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE;
 targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses.CodesAndGuidelinesSectionStatus = Entities.Enums.ProjectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE;
 targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses.ExecutiveSummarySectionStatus = Entities.Enums.ProjectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE;
 targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses.ExhaustEquipmentSectionStatus = Entities.Enums.ProjectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE;
 targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses.InfiltrationSectionStatus = Entities.Enums.ProjectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE;
        ......
        ......
```

there are  10 or more similar status properties that i need to update one by one with `INCOMPLETE` enum status so i have tried below approach using reflection method to update all at once but stuck at setting the value

```
 PropertyInfo[] properties = targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            
 foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
 {
    var propValue = property.GetValue(targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses);

    if (propValue is ProjectSectionStage)
    {
       property.SetValue() // not sure how to update here 
    }
 }
```

Is there any way to update these statuses using reflection with `Incomplete` enum status. Could any one please let us know  idea in suggestions how to update these using reflection that would be very grateful to me.

thanks in advance

Update :

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
     var propValue = property.GetValue(targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses);

     if (propValue is ProjectSectionStage)
     {
           property.SetValue(targetDesignProject, ProjectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE, null); 
           // getting an error - Object does not match target type
      }
 }
```

Comment: Could any one please point me in the right direction why i am getting that error

Comment: There is another option which name is Automapper that use the reflection under the bottom layer. You can use this library to map your object property to another object property.
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem using below code

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
     var propValue = property.GetValue(targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses);

     if (propValue is ProjectSectionStage)
     {
           property.SetValue(targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses, ProjectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE, null); 
           // getting an error - Object does not match target type
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            
 foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
 {
    var propValue = property.GetValue(targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses);

    if (propValue is ProjectSectionStage)
    {
       property.SetValue(targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses, propValue)

       // You can do this if you want
       // var newPropValue = rojectSectionStage.INCOMPLETE;
       // property.SetValue(targetDesignProject.SectionStatuses, newPropValue)
    }
 }
```

Also, you can refer to these page if you want more documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=netcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_SetValue_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object___